# how to use arrays as variables in a function

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I have imported a .csv file of data into python. As you can see, I have set 3 variables (`nu0i`, `si` and `gammai`) each one set to a column (1,2,3) of the .csv file (The file is 318000 rows in length).

```
 import numpy as np
   
 V = np.arange((10**4)/0.85,(10**4)/0.8, 0.01)
    i=1
    while i < n-1:

 nu0i = arr[i,1]    

 si = arr[i,2]

 gammai = arr[i,3]
```

What I need to do is to return the value of this function defined below (`abspec2(v)` is itself an array) for each row value of the variables (hence my attempt to loop through the rows from `i = 1` to `i = n-1`). Ultimately i need to sum all the arrays returned by the function.

```
def abspec2(v):
    a = si/np.pi
    b = gammai/(gammai**2+(v - nu0i )**2)
    sigma = a*b
    return sigma

print(abspec2(v))
i+=1
```

There is obviously a fault in my logic here, any help or hints would be massively appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand what `v - nu0i` means. v is just a list. but you can extract a column simply with `column=array[:,index_of_column]`. indices start at 0, not 1

Comment: Is v the same as `V` or is `v = V[i]`?